# Comentar atributo ID em elemento

Tags: jquery, html

Estou com uma duvida em Jquery e gostaria de saber se isso é possivel.

Tenho um elemento:

```
<input type="text" id="meuid" class="minhaclasse" >
```

Gostaria que a minha propriedade id ficasse inoperante, porém podendo ativá-la, por exemplo comentando e removendo o comentário:

```
<input type="text" /*id="meuid"*/ class="minhaclasse" >
```

Isso é possível? Alguma sugestão para fazer isso?

Comment: Sei que existe como remover $("p").removeAttr("id");

Comment: Sim, realmente existe. Porém preciso que apenas comente, pois se remover não ha como retorna-lo.

Comment: E se renomear? Serve? por exemplo: id="meuid" para old-id="meuid"

Comment: Interessante, como isso funciona ? @FabianoCacinPinel

Comment: teria que guardar o valor do id, remover o id e adicionar o atributo old-id com o valor guardado, pelo que pesquisei não existe nada pronto que renomeie um atributo, mas talvez daria para resolver renomeando o valor o id, ficando assim id="@meuid" isso daria para fazer fácil da seguinte forma $('#meuid').attr('id','@meuid'); . Talvez seria mais fácil você explicar melhor o que você que fazer. Deve ter outra solução sem precisar fazer isso.

Comment: se explicar o motivo para fazer isso, pode ter solução mais adequada.

Answer (score 1):

Possível não é em todos navegadores, pois eles removem os comentários das tags. Comentar o atributo é perigoso, pois é necessário modificar o `outerHTML` do seu elemento, o que acaba recriando/removendo seus elementos (se tiverem uma referência em JavaScript, serão apenas mortos, mas podem ser declarados na página novamente com `HTMLElement().appendChild`, etc.).

Para compreender melhor, teste esse snippet:

```js
// Observação: em navegadores modernos, elementos com id
// são disponíveis em 'window' se tiverem caracteres válidos.

var minhaDiv = div;

document.body.innerHTML = '<div id="div">hey</div>';

// "old"
alert("Velha div: " + minhaDiv.innerHTML);

// "hey" - essa não é mais a 'minhaDiv'
alert("Nova div: " + div.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="div">old</div>
```

Observação: para comentar em HTML é usado <!---->.

Modificar o "id" de um elemento só vai fazer uma complicação com seu código.

Continuando, seria melhor você adicionar/remover o attributo "id" com o valor sempre memorizado, por exemplo:

```
// Você pode usar diretamente 'removeAttr' e
// 'attr' (com o id específico) para remover/adicionar o atributo id
// (portanto, é necessário
// jQuery.fn.each para percorrer cada elemento em uma função
// de toggle)

jQuery.fn.toggleAttr = function(attrName, value) {

    this.each(function() {

        // this é um elemento puro do JavaScript aqui, então:
        // $(this) --> lista de elementos do jQuery
        var $me = $(this);

        // verifica se o atributo não existe (ou se é inativo)
        if ($me.attr(attrName) === undefined || $me.attr(attrName) === false) {
            $me.attr(attrName, value);

        } else $me.removeAttr(attrName);
    });
};

var $input = $("#meuid");

// memoriza o id
var id = $input.attr('id');

// remove o atributo id
$input.toggleAttr("id", id);

// adiciona o atributo id
$input.toggleAttr("id", id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sim possível para comentar, mas html não conhece `<input /*id="blabla"*/>` e apenas trocar elemento `id` para `_id`. Enviando o código abaixo, bem simples código para duas forma jquery ou javascript puro para entender melhor.

```js
/* jQuery */
var elemento1 = $('[id="meuid1"]');
var nome1 = elemento1.attr('id');
elemento1.removeAttr('id').attr('_id', nome1);

/* Javascript Puro */
var elemento2 = document.querySelector('[id="meuid2"]');
var nome2 = elemento2.getAttribute('id');
elemento2.removeAttribute('id');
elemento2.setAttribute('_id', nome2);

/* Resultado de Console */
console.log($('.minhaclasse')[0]);
console.log($('.minhaclasse')[1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
jQuery<br>
<input type="text" id="meuid1" class="minhaclasse">
<br><br>
Javascript Puro<br>
<input type="text" id="meuid2" class="minhaclasse">
```

Answer (score 1):

Segue uma implementação com alguns controles para garantir a integridade das propriedades.

```js
var AttrManager = function (element) {
  this.attr = {};
  this.element = element;
}

AttrManager.prototype.toggle = function (name) {
  if (name in this.attr) {
    this.element.setAttribute(name, this.attr[name]);
    delete this.attr[name];
  } else {
    this.attr[name] = this.element.getAttribute(name);
    this.element.removeAttribute(name);
  }
}

var teste = document.getElementById("teste");
var attrManager = new AttrManager(teste);

console.log(teste);
attrManager.toggle("id");
console.log(teste);
attrManager.toggle("data-teste");
console.log(teste);
attrManager.toggle("data-teste");
console.log(teste);
attrManager.toggle("id");
console.log(teste);
```

```html
<div id="teste" class="teste" data-teste>
</div>
```

Comment: Parece que o op está perguntando como fazer isso com o uso de jQuery, mas boa solução

Answer (score 0):

O que eu faria nesse caso é o seguinte:

```
<input type="text" data-id="minhaId">
```

data-id seria uma campo genérico com a minha id apenas para armazena-lá através do html e quando eu precisasse ativar a minha id faria:

```
//PEGO O VALOR DA ID FAKE

   valor_na_fake_id = $("data-id").val();

//COLOCO DE VOLTA NO ELEMENTO COMO ID

    $("data-id").attr('id',valor_na_fake_id);

// O RESULTADO SERIA

    <input type="text" data-id="minhaId" id="minhaId">
```